# Is there a way to get column headers to wordwrap in SharePoint lists?

Tags: list

My column header needs to be quite long, but the content of the column is only a few pixels wide, so loads of white space and horizontal scrolling required to see the rest of the content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use SharePoint Designer to edit the AllItems.aspx view on this list. Insert this style inside the content place holder:

```
<style type= "text/css"> 
  .ms-vh2 {white-space: normal} 
</style>
```

This will override the style for the column headers which is set to white-space: nowrap

Comment: If you can't or dont want to use SPD you can also put this in a Content Editor Web Part (CEWP) using the HTML Source option.

Comment: I've added a few lines of CSS to make it work in 2007/2010 and with non-filterable columns http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/06/word-wrapping-sharepoint-list-column-headers/

Answer (score 1):

There is also a way to wrap the columns individually using JavaScript by removing the `nowrap` attribute from the column header.

See [Wrap ListViewWebPart Column Headers](http://kitmenke.com/blog/2010/07/08/wrap-listviewwebpart-colum-headers/) for more info (shameless link to my blog).

Answer (score 0):

The bast/easy way -> Add JSLink to each view where you want add/remove "white-space".

```
(function() {
var addClassToField = {};
addClassToField.Templates = {};
// overrideNameField.OnPreRender = RenameColumn;
addClassToField.OnPostRender = AddClass;
addClassToField.Templates.Fields = {
    "Category": {
        "View": FieldToAddClass
    }
}
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(addClassToField)})() 



function FieldToAddClass(ctx) {
      return "<div class='to-whiteSpace'>" + ctx.CurrentItem["Category"] + "
   </div>";
   }

function AddClass() {
    //white-space: nowrap;
    var headerAddClass = document.querySelector("[name=Category]").parentNode;
    if (headerAddClass.style.whiteSpace != "nowrap") {
        headerAddClass.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
    }
    var elementsAddClass = document.getElementsByClassName("to-whiteSpace");
    var elementsAddClassQuant = elementsAddClass.length;
    for (var el = 0; el < elementsAddClassQuant; el++) {
        elementsAddClass[el].parentNode.style.whiteSpace = "nowrap";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

easier way:

```
(function () {
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};

overrideCtx.OnPostRender = [HeaderWrap];

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();


function HeaderWrap(inCtx) {
     
   var headers = document.getElementsByTagName("th");
   for (var h = 0; h < headers.length; ++h){
      headers[h].style.whiteSpace = "normal";
   } //for
} //function
```